# Oracle Instance has been stopped for no reason

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have free Oracle Cloud always free instance. I was not able to connect to it by ssh and it looks like it was stopped.

I cannot re-run it. I get:

> Unable to start instance: Instance ocid1.instance.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.antheljscauatxycmb7qvp36l6jmfffvhfjqspjo6zz3xzbjletwexs7fvsa is disabled and will not accept any action requests. Please contact customer support to reenable.

Customer support doesn't work. Any idea what to do and why it was stopped ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "customer support doesn't work"?

Comment: @Joe From my brief investigation, the Oracle support service is only offered to paying Oracle customers - so if you're only using the "always free" tier products and attempt to reach customer support via chat you won't get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the same issue today with my always-free VM. [This Redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/oraclecloud/comments/pcfvz4/solution_unable_to_start_instance_instance_is/) from a few months back is really helpful.

The solution is to create a backup of the boot volume, then terminate the stopped VM instance **without deleting the associated boot volume**, and finally create a new instance matching the specs of the original VM using the "Create Instance" option from the boot volume page.

The Redit post provides a nice, clear set of instructions. Worked perfectly for me.

As to the reason for Oracle disabling the instance in the first place, @Anupam's answer is very helpful, though I'm not sure where this info came from. I certainly didn't get a heads-up email like the one sent out when Oracle indicated they were going to pause my transaction database.

Comment: I have the same problem. Upgrade to paid account and they start charging me using a supposed free ARM Ampere A1 VM. Contacting the billing three times from email ,call and rasing ticket and still no response. They even charge me while the service was stopped 5 days ago. Poor service form Oracle

Comment: But now I can only select an instance that has 1gb ram, even though previously I had a much greater machine which was supposedly free tier eligible

Answer (score 2):

Is that an ampere A1 flex instance that was stopped? are you within the initial 30 days free trail or it got expired?

[image]

Comment: my trail has expired 20 days ago

Comment: still you need to try this out, this works for me